# How to convert a MongoDB replica set to a stand alone server

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Consider, I have 4 replicate sets and the config is as follows:

```
{
 "_id": "rs_0",
 "version": 5,
 "members" : [
  {"_id": 1, "host": "127.0.0.1:27001"},
  {"_id": 2, "host": "127.0.0.1:27002"},
  {"_id": 3, "host": "127.0.0.1:27003"},
  {"_id": 4, "host": "127.0.0.1:27004"}
 ]
}
```

I am able to connect to all sets using 
`mongo --port <port>`

There are documents for getting information on [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/#convert-a-standalone-to-a-replica-set), but can anyone tell me how to convert back to standalone from replica set?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just remove a host from replica set (`rs.remove('host:port')`), relaunch it without `replSet` parameter and it's standalone again.

Comment: If you don't want it to hold its info you can also delete the `local` db

Comment: Not working:

```
bippo:PRIMARY> rs.remove('rudi.dev:27017');
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't find self in new replset config",
        "code" : 13433,
        "ok" : 0
}
bippo:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
        "_id" : "bippo",
        "version" : 1,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "rudi.dev:27017"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Write a complete doc for convert ReplicaSet to single server [tecnicume](http://tecnicume.blogspot.it/2016/02/mongodb-migrazione-da-replicaset.html).

Comment: About the comment suggesting the deletion of the `local` database: You never know what future DB versions will insert into this DB, and the comment may be readable years after when it actually made sense and was applicable, but this could change over time, so that deleting the `local` db could result in a damaged server. Best is to backup the suggestion with a link to the Documentation which claims that it's OK to do that in order to archive one's goals.

Answer (score 41):

Remove all secondary hosts from replica set (rs.remove('host:port')), restart the mongo deamon without replSet parameter (editing /etc/mongo.conf) and the secondary hosts starts in standalone mode again.

The Primary host is tricky one, because you can't remove it from the replica set with rs.remove. 
Once you have only the primary node in the replica set, you should exit mongo shell and stop mongo. Then you edit the /etc/mongo.conf and remove the replSet parameter and start mongo again.
Once you start mongo you are already in standalone mode, but the mongo shell will prompt a message like:

> 2015-07-31T12:02:51.112+0100 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset

to remove the warning  you can do 2 procedures:
1) Droping the local db  and restarting mongo:

```
use local
db.dropDatabase();

/etc/init.d/mongod restart
```

2)Or if you don't want to be so radical, you can do:

```
use local
db.system.replset.find()
```

and it will prompt a message like:

```
{ "_id" : "replicaSetName", "version" : 1, "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "hostprimary:mongoport" } ] }
```

then you will erase it using:

```
db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "replicaSetName", "version" : 1, "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "hostprimary:mongoport" } ] })
```

and it will probably prompt:

```
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
```

Now, you can restart the mongo and the warning should be gone, and you will have your mongo in standalone mode without warnings

Comment: I had to run `rs.initiate()` to recreate the replication cluster again and make the node PRIMARY. Thanks!

Comment: ```not authorized on local to execute command { delete: \"system.replset\", deletes: [ { q: { _id: \"rs0\" }, limit: 0.0 } ], ordered: true }``` on doing the remove.  What role is needed to be able to delete from ```system.replset```?

Comment: in MongoDB 4.0 it seems you can't remove the `replset.*` collections in the `local` db. I had to drop the `local` db

Answer (score 9):

On an Ubuntu Machine

1. Stop your mongo server
2. open /etc/mongod.conf
3. Comment the replication and replSetName line

> ```
> #replication:
>    #replSetName: rs0
> ```

4. Start your mongo server and go to mongo shell
5. drop local database

> 

```
use local

db.dropDatabase()
```

6. Restart mongo

Comment: Any of the answers here worked for me, except this.. Thanks..

Comment: This can be used not just to convert mongodb replicaset back to standalone but vice versa as well to re-initiate standalone to replicaset.

Answer (score 3):

The [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/) suggests the following to perform maintenance on a replica set member, which brings the the replica set member into standalone mode for further operations. With little modification it can be made standalone:

1. If node in concern is the only node in a shard, drain the chunks to other shards as per [MongoDB documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/), or else the sharded database will break, i.e.

   - Make sure balancer is enabled by connecting to mongos and run `sh.startBalancer(timeout, interval)`
   - For the shard in concern, go to admin database and `db.adminCommand( { removeShard: "mongodb0" } )`
   - Check draining status by repeating above removeShard command, wait for draining to complete
2. If node in concern is primary, do `rs.stepDown(300)`
3. Stop the node by running `db.shutdownServer()`
4. Change the yaml config by:

   - commenting out **replication.replSetName** (--replSetName in command line)
   - commenting out **sharding.clusterRole** for shard or config server (--shardsvc and --configsvr in command line)
   - commenting out **net.port**, then change it to a different port (--port in command line)
5. Start the mongod instance
6. If change is permanent, go to other mongod instance and run `rs.remove("host:port")`

After this, the node in concern should be up and running in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

1. Go to mongo shell on Secondary servers
2. Stop the secondary servers by using below command :
   use admin
   db.shutdownServer()
3. Go to Linux shell- on secondary servers and type below command :

sudo service mongod stop

Starting the MongoDB replication -

- Go to Linux shell - on secondary servers and type below command :

  sudo service mongod start
  Starting the MongoDB replication -
- Go to primary and type below commands to start the replication :

a] rs.initiate()

b] rs.add("Secondar -1:port no")

c] rs.add("Secondary-2:port no")

d] rs.add({ "_id" : 3, "host" : "Hidden_member:port no", "priority" : 0,
"hidden" : true })

e] rs.status()

Comment: AFAIK your primary will NOT become a standalon server. It will become the primary member of a replica set that contains only a single member.