# MongoDB replica set no primary, need to force new primary

Tags: mongodb

We have a mongoDB replica set which has 3 nodes;

1. Primary
2. Secondary
3. Arbiter

Somehow our replica set has ended up with 1 & 2 both being set as secondary members. I'm not sure how this has happened (we have had a server migration which one of the nodes runs on, but only one).

Anyway, I've been trying to re-elect a new primary for the replica set following the guide [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/)

I'm unable to just use

```
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

as it will only work if directed at the primary (which I don't have).

Using the force parameter

```
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true})
```

would appear to work but then when I requery the status of the replica set, both servers are still only showing as Secondary.

Why hasn't the force reconfig worked? Currently the database is locked out whatever I try.

Comment: Can you post the output of rs.status()? This will provide current state of your replica set members.

Comment: Not even close to relating to a programming question. Please submit to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. This is not the place for subjects not directly related to programming topics.

Comment: This will probably be locked soon as it isn't a programming question.  Rather than try to force one, you can use the "votes" parameter to tune the primary http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#local.system.replset.members[n].votes.  A node will never vote for itself, so whichever you give more votes will be the secondary.  You can simply tune this value and force an election to switch primary

Comment: Fine, I'll ask it on the DBA site.

Answer (score 6):

**1.Convert all nodes to standalone.**

Stop mongod deamon and edit `/etc/mongod.conf` to comment `replSet` option.

Start mongod deamon.

**2.Use `mongodump` to backup data for all nodes.**

Reference from mongo docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

**3.Log into each node, and drop `local` database.**

Doing this will delete replica set config on the node.

Or you can just delete a record in collection `system.replset` in local db, like it said here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745150/4242454

**4.Start all nodes with `replSet` option.**

**5.On the previous data node (not arbiter), initialize a new replica set.**

**6.Finally, reconfig replica set with `rs.reconfig`.**

Comment: Saved us, thanks for the answer. For others - drop local db: `use local` `db.dropDatabase()`, initialize new replica set: `rs.initiate()`

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation: because arbiter received information that he has most recent opTime timestamp.

It found in log: grep ELECTION /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

```
"ARBITER-NODE:27017" ... "reason":"candidate's data is staler than mine. candidate's last applied OpTime: .."
```

The reason for this behavior is that the data-nodes were restored from a backup snapshot, while the arbitrator is not. if it is acceptable
the solution is temporary stop arbiter node.