# Can't connect to MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am totally new to MongoDB and node.js and facing this issue.

Do you have any ideas what causes this error?

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 18.158.79.102:27017 closed
   at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
   at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
   at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
 reason: TopologyDescription {
   type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
   setName: 'atlas-i749eb-shard-0',
   maxSetVersion: null,
   maxElectionId: null,
   servers: Map(3) {
     'cluster0-shard-00-00.fivve.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
     'cluster0-shard-00-02.fivve.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
     'cluster0-shard-00-01.fivve.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
   },
   stale: false,
   compatible: true,
   compatibilityError: null,
   logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
   heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
   localThresholdMS: 15,
   commonWireVersion: 9
 }
}
```

I checked security settings, added outbound rule, reinstall MongoDB but it still doesn't work.

Please find my code below

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let connectionString = `mongodb+srv://Ivan:<navaro>@cluster0.fivve.mongodb.net/<first-data-base-users>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
}) 
 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') 
})

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log('Helooooooooooooooo')
})
//

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(client => {
        console.log('Connected to Database')
        const db = client.db('first-data-base-users')
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot connect to a "MongoClient" - The Mongo client connects to a Mongo database (or name it "Mongo server" or "Mongo service")

Comment: Do you have just a replica set or a sharded cluster?

Comment: I pasted the error message in the body of question.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if it's a replica set or a shared cluster. Where I can check it?

Comment: Sorry, I mistake the first block with your code.

Comment: Did you install the MongoDB (server)? Then you should know whether you configured a sharded cluster - you can't do it by accident!

Comment: I installed it, totally by myself, but when you do it, it doesn't require this knowledge.

Comment: Come on! You created the database but you don't know whether you configured a stand-alone MongoDB, a Replica Set or a Sharded Cluster? What are the configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

The error says "ReplicaSetNoPrimary". It appears you have set up a cluster with 3 shards

```
cluster0-shard-00-00.fivve.mongodb.net:27017
cluster0-shard-00-02.fivve.mongodb.net:27017
cluster0-shard-00-01.fivve.mongodb.net:27017
```

but you have not designated a primary shard in your replica set.

Read more about the [primary shard in the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-primary/).

Check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41181622/675721) for details on how to reconfigure your cluster.

Comment: Could you show me an example of code that fixes it? I've read stuff that you sent and official documentation also, but I can't figure out where exactly in my code I should to implement it.

Comment: @IvanBozhko unfortunately it's not in your code that this must be fixed, if I am correct. My understanding is that the cloud cluster is set up incorrectly. The configuration on the MongoDB servers must change. Is anyone else using those same MongoDB servers? You could also try changing `connectionString` and replacing `cluster0.fivve.mongodb.net` with `cluster0-shard-00-00.fivve.mongodb.net`, but I don't think this will work.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to fix it in this way. I use it alone. I'll play around, thank you for your advice. Already fixed connectionString, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @IvanBozhko, I think your original `connectionString` was correct, and once the server configuration is fixed it should work. Good luck

Comment: @IvanBozhko were you able to get it to work?